# Повествование или описание действий?

Tags: оформление-текста

Как их отличить друг от друга?

В  ЕГЭ есть задание А 29. Нужно определить тип речи фрагмента текста. Идет повествование.  А в ответе - описание. Учитель объяснила, что это описание действий, но я не понял.

Answer (score 1):

Есть типы речи: описание, повествование, рассуждение, а есть сочинение на тему "Описание действий".Сочинение на тему"Описание действий" - это описание процесса, чаще творчества. Сочинение на тему"Описание действий" содержит одновременно и повествование, и описание, и рассуждение.

Пример сочинения на тему "Описание действий"
Один раз я увидела девочку, сидевшую ранним утром в саду за мольбертом. Она рисовала пейзаж, находящийся перед ней. 
Я подошла тогда, когда девочка только начинала рисовать. Сначала она просто стояла и рассматривала цветущие деревья. Остановив свой выбор на бело-розовых ветвях яблони, юная художница стала намечать контуры будущего рисунка, едва касаясь бумаги простым карандашом. Потом она принялась  раскрашивать рисунок акварелью. Девочка смешивала краски разных цветов на палитре, каждый раз внимательно сверяя получившийся цвет с теми оттенками, которые имели цветы яблони. Мазок - взгляд! Мазок - взгляд! Художница не делала лишних движений, она работала старательно и последовательно. В первую очередь девочка зарисовала верхнюю часть рисунка, затем принялась закрашивать нижнюю. Сначала мне казалось, что в красках получалось не очень хорошо, однако, когда картина была окончена полностью, получилось красиво. 
Работа была сделана аккуратно. На рисунке получилось все точно, как в саду.

Comment: Есть такой тест на определение типов речи: можно запечатлеть объект н и рассмотреть его детали (на слайде или в воображении)- это описание, можно запечатлеть на разных слайдах и проследить завязку, развитие действия, кульминацию, развязку - повествование.Если это речь или мысль, которую нельзя запечатлеть и состоит она из тезиса , доказательств его, вывода - это рассуждение.

Comment: Не понял. По-вашему получается, что  описание  действий - это текст и с описанием, и с повествованием? Я, пожалуй,  поясню вопрос.

Comment: Неплохо бы посмотреть текст. Что там, описание одного действия - перечисление его признаков? Вот описание чувства возможно, например, описание вдохновения, а описание действий - странно. О чём текст?